# Switch Taps from Activitys by buttons, etc

Tags: android

I have following TapControl in the StartActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for A Tap
    TabSpec atapspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ATap");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    atapespec.setIndicator("ATap", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.state_atap));
    Intent atapIntent = new Intent(this, ATapActivity.class);
    atapspec.setContent(atapIntent);

    // Tab for B Tap
    TabSpec btapspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("BTap");
    btapspec.setIndicator("BTap", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.state_btap));
    Intent btapIntent = new Intent(this, BtapActivity.class);
    btapspec.setContent(btapIntent);



    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(atapspec); // Adding a tab
    tabHost.addTab(btapspec); // Adding b tab


}
```

Each Tap has its own Activity. 
Now my problem, how can I switch with a button to the next Tap-Activity?
 I tried to start just the Activity but then the Tap-control was missing.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, BTapActivity.class));
```

I found that it should be sometion like that:

```
setCurrentTabByTag("BTab");
```

but i don't know how.

EDIT:

When I put "tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("BTap");" on the end of the onCreate Method, BTap is selected.Therefore it is the correct command. But from another Activity I'm not able to access the tabHost.
When I make the the tabHost to a global Object, The App crashes:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```

I tried it like this from the Tab-Activity:

```
startActivity StartAct = new startActivity ();
StartAct.setTap("BTap");
```

This Method is in the StartActivity:

```
public void setTap(String tap) {

    tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(tap);
}
```

What can I do? Sorry, but I'm a beginner ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TabHost's `setCurrentTab(int index)` function to open tabs programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, the only thing I missed was TabHost tabHost =  (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);